# dojo fx.fadeIn/fx.fadeOut

Tags: javascript, html, dojo

Have simple question. Don't know why it's not working. Its should be red box that can fade in and fade out on click, but nothing happens. I'm trying to solve this problem for more then 2 days and i can't see the answer what I'm doing bad :/

```html
 <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Tutorial: Hello Dojo!</title>
        
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/dojo/dojo.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/dijit/themes/tundra/tundra.css" />
            
     <script src="dojo/dojo/dojo.js" data-dojo-config="async: true"></script>
     
        <script type="text/javascript">
        require(["dojo/_base/fx", "dojo/on", "dojo/dom", "dojo/domReady!"], function(fx, on, dom) {
            var fadeOutButton = dom.byId("fadeOutButton"),
                fadeInButton = dom.byId("fadeInButton"),
                fadeTarget = dom.byId("fadeTarget");
    
            on(fadeOutButton, "click", function(evt){
                fx.fadeOut({ node: fadeTarget }).play();
            });
            on(fadeInButton, "click", function(evt){
                fx.fadeIn({ node: fadeTarget }).play();
            });
        });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <button id="fadeOutButton">Fade block out</button>
    <button id="fadeInButton">Fade block in</button>
    
    <div id="fadeTarget" class="red-block" style="margin-left: 20px; height: 300px; width: 200px; background-color: red; margin-top: 20px; text-align: center">
        A red block
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Something with a syntax probably, but i don't know what

Comment: Do you  get any errors in the console? Which version of Dojo are you using?

Comment: There must be something else at play here because a simple copy and paste of your code into a fiddle makes it work fine: https://jsfiddle.net/argduze0/

Comment: Ok it worked when i opened it in browser, but in Eclipse Preview Serwer not... Other things, like "wiping" works fine, only with fading i had problems. Maybe Eclipse has problems with showing fading function. Anyway thanks for help :)